# Quantity Bought Confusion on Magento Software

Tags: magento

We have a Magento software and we are using  platform to sell travel deals.
Now when we for instance block say 20 spaces and someone makes a purchase for say 10 people in one bulk purchase, the Quantity bought shows as 1 and it is possible to buy for more people because because the remaining quantity left shows as 19 out of 20 and this is a huge problem because people will still be able to purchase products that are sold out.
Does anyone know how to make the Quantity remaining be a subtraction of the total bought from the total quantity (as opposed to seeing every bulk purchase as 1 Quantity?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think we need to see, how you created your product, what type, do you use (simple, bundle, configurable...). If you could post this info, would help us! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are defining stock value for block size which is not good way. Add custom attribute for block size and disable stock management, follow steps below

1. Admin -> System -> Configuration
2. Select Inventory under Catalog (on left nav bar)
3. Look Product Stock Options, Set No to Manage Stock. and Save